# Java Quarkus running a command line runner without main method

Tags: java, quarkus

Hello I'm trying to follow the example here https://quarkus.io/blog/introducing-command-mode/

So I wrote a simple class with Java 11

```
@QuarkusMain
public class CommandRunner implements QuarkusApplication {

    @Override
    public int run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("hello command line runner");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I build this with mvn clean package to get the .jar file

i then run java myjar.jar and i get the error

> Error: Could not find or load main class

I thought Quarkus would generate a main method if I didn't provide one?

Comment: As the page says, try including `-Dnative` rather than making a jar

Comment: @OneCricketeer i did try but that seem to download some docker image. I just want to run this as a command line tool

Comment: I think it tries to install GraalVm, maybe, not Docker

Comment: Which jar file are you running?

Answer (score 1):

You have to run it with:

```
java -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar
```